# How to make an executable installer of java application?

Tags: windows-installer, exe, r.java-file

I created a java project in NetBeans named "Example" and in this project I've created a class named "File.java" which contains JFrame and some buttons and all its feature. And also I've used an external library in this project named "jSerialComm".. Now my problem is I want to create an exe installer. When I double click on it my program should open (That JFrame should open)..

I searched a lot, I found many answers but none of them worked can anyone tell me how to do that.. How can i create an executable file (which will work on double click) from a .java file..

And one more question can we convert our java file into an exe installer such that which will work on every OS (without JDK/JRE)

EDIT:- I've created my project in Apache NetBeans IDE 17 by choosing "Java With Ant-->Java Application"